# List empty folders in windows and insert a file into them

Tags: windows, powershell

I use a tool to upload windows folders to Google Drive. It's a free tool.

This tool does not upload empty folders. Therefore, if I want to upload a folder with 30 folders inside and 5 of them are empty, in Drive I will only have 25 folders.

I would like to know if in windows, I can list all empty folders and a directory and insert a file of any type a "test.txt" in all of them, just so that I can upload all folders without restriction.

Thank you very much!

I found ways to list empty folders by powershell, but not to insert a file in each empty folder found.

https://sqlcrespi.com/2021/02/01/quick-tip-9-listando-os-diretorios-vazios-com-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straight forward, you can use `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate all directories then `Where-Object` to filter those folders not having any files or folders in them and lastly `New-Item` to create a new file in them:

```
# enumerate all directories in "initialfolder"
$createdFiles = Get-ChildItem path\to\initialfolder -Directory -Recurse |
    # filter those directorires not having any files or folders in them
    # (this includes hidden and system)
    Where-Object { -not ($_.EnumerateFileSystemInfos() | Select-Object -First 1) } |
    # for each empty folder, create a new file with name "test.txt"
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path { $_.FullName } -Name test.txt
```